# Make Keyboard popup automatically on entry

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a grid in Xamain forms and I want on the selection event to call the keyboard I thought doing this word wok.

I am using the plugin dialogue kit to display a numeric entry but my quesiton is the keyboard is only displaying on the text box when it has focus how Do I force the keyboard to come up so the user does not have to click into the field.

```
 new Entry()
 {
                Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric
 };

 var resultQty = await Plugin.DialogKit.CrossDiaglogKit.Current.GetInputTextAsync("Test", $"Please goto Bin {item.BinName} , and enter the visible stock of the item." + item.Name, null, Keyboard.Numeric);
```

The code from Dialog kit shows that it attempts to place a focus on the entry field.

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="25">
        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
        <Entry x:Name="txtInput" Keyboard="{Binding Keyboard}"/>
        <StackLayout Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="{Binding OK}" Clicked="Confirm_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Button Text="{Binding Cancel}" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

You will see here that the dialog kit calls the above few as such

```
public Task<string> GetInputTextAsync(string title, string message,string currentText = null, Keyboard keyboard = null)
{           
        if (keyboard == null) keyboard = Keyboard.Default;
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var _dialogView = new Plugin.DialogKit.Views.InputView(title, message,currentText,keyboard);
        _dialogView.FocusEntry();
        _dialogView.Picked += (s, o) => { cts.SetResult(o); PopupNavigation.PopAsync(); };
        PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new PopupPage { Content = _dialogView });
        return cts.Task;
  }
```

Which as you can see is calling the but i think the placement of this is wrong as its before its pops onto the view.

public void FocusEntry()
   {
            txtInput.Focus();
   }

​

Comment: just call the entry's Focus event

Comment: @Jason the entry is inside the Plugin Dialog Kit i dont have control over that other than telling it to display the numeric text box.

Comment: @Jason I tried to make it popup but it still did not work the entry field is within rg popups.

Comment: @Jason plesae see my above edits.

Comment: @rogue39nin given that this is an external library you could either: create a pull request with the changes and hope the maintainer respond "quickly", or you can do the PR but at the same time fork the project and do the changes and use a dll until the PR is merged and your change becomes part of the original repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some test and found you should Call the `FocusEntry` after `PopUp` to force the keyboard to come up automatically.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var resultQty = await GetInputTextAsync("Test", $"Please goto Bin, the visible stock of the item.", null, Keyboard.Numeric);
}

public async Task<string> GetInputTextAsync(string title, string message, string currentText = null, Keyboard keyboard = null)
{
    if (keyboard == null) keyboard = Keyboard.Default;
    var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var _dialogView = new Plugin.DialogKit.Views.InputView(title, message, currentText, keyboard);
    _dialogView.Picked += (s, o) => { cts.SetResult(o); PopupNavigation.PopAsync(); };
    await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new PopupPage { Content = _dialogView });

    //Call the FocusEntry after PopUp
    _dialogView.FocusEntry();

    return await cts.Task;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jack I tried that using the install google gboard the popup still comes up first so it does. and the user as to physically enter into the field before it will popup

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point, when I test the above code, the keyboard pop up before user enter into the field, is this your want?

Comment: jack i am using a huweii y9 2019 and that does not happen on mine the popup stil comes up first even though I adjusted my code to be that of the same I removed the nuget reference and pointed to my local dll which I just compiled instead

Comment: @rogue39nin So open an issue or create a pull request on Github would help you better as it is a third-part libary. I test it on iOS simulator and it works on my side.